# Make the mobile version of the sites moderator-friendly

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, mobile-web

I keep on having issues using the mobile sites as a moderator on an iPhone. The following are relatively easy fixes that would make a lot of difference for me (and hopefully other mods):

- I can't delete comments (lately there is no "x", previously it was there but it was almost impossible to hit)
- I don't see the flags anywhere, please show them somewhere near the top of the page.
- In order to navigate between main and meta I have to scroll down to the bottom of the page. However, the page is very very long. The link should be at the top.
- Please make the post notices visible, they are not implemented for mobile sites.

Comment: Even just some of these would be helpful. It's a pain to delete comments now, and often they're the easiest to clean up on the go.

Comment: Yes. Please. Please!

Comment: FYI: if you go to a page, like [about](/about), that doesn't do mobile, you can see the flags at the top. Not mobile-friendly, but not totally impossible to find.  I think flags should show up the same place, or right next to, where the inbox count shows up.

Comment: meta/main/chat links should be in the little menu, not straight-out on the top of the page.

Comment: The delete or edit comments don't show up even for non-moderators, for example, I posted a comment yesterday on a question, I must've been half asleep because what I wrote made no sense and I couldn't delete the comment until this morning using my PC

Comment: I agree that you *can* go to the full site for things like `/admin`, but why does it have to be completely left out of the navigation concept on mobile? Sometimes I just want to check if my site has any open flags, and having to type or use bookmarks on a phone can be more cumbersome than it needs to be...

Comment: Your second bullet (the flags) has been asked as a feature-request [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111212/164138)