# Mobile site: delete own post

Tags: support, mobile-web

It would appear that deleting your own post doesn't actually do anything from the mobile site.

I just had a little mixup- I prematurely posted a question (by hitting return on my phone when editing the title, possible another issue of its own) but I stopped the page load, so it didn't appear that I had actually posted anything.

When I had finished typing the question (but hadn't posted it), I then noticed the premature question that I had accidentally posted, which had been down voted and closed. From the mobile site, I hit the delete button under the question content, as I wanted to delete it. It prompted me for confirmation, and I click yes, and the page refreshed. The question remained, but I assumed I was just voting like the people who closed my question. (The confirmation prompt actually says Vote too) I then went on to create a new question, with a near identical title to the premature one, and the correct body content.

I was then informed that I had posted an extended duplicate, and was told to edit the previous post. So I did just that, and tried deleting the duplicate I had just posted (from full site). To my suprise, the post was almost immediately removed...

Comment: For reference, [the question is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995105/why-are-apps-bundled-with-cross-platform-gui-tool-kits-on-windows).

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151889/make-the-mobile-version-of-the-sites-moderator-friendly (about mod powers on mobile sites).

Comment: Workaround: since the mobile site is suboptimal in other ways too, use the Full Site link at the bottom of the page. I've not looked back.